# Select without top then assume top N

Tags: sql-server

My program connects to SQL Server. The program has a lot of Select statements. If the program executes

```
Select * from MyTable
```

I want the SQL server to only return top 200 rows instead of returning all rows.

Only if the program explicitly executes

```
Select top all * from MyTable
```

the SQL engine then returns all rows.

Is there an option in SQL Server to do this? If not, how can it be implemented?

Comment: why not add TOP to the selects, and remove the TOP if you need all the data?

Comment: You can't just tell sql server to get you 200 rows on every select statement. Besides, when you start mentioning the top 200 rows you are introducing the concept of order. How would sql server know which 200 rows you want? So, if you use top you really need to add an order by or your results are inconsistent.

Comment: [You can](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx), but it will override the explicit `top all` too.

Comment: He kind of can, but there are some complications. `SET ROWCOUNT` sets the default but on everything, including triggers etc.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for the info. I assume [the undefined order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms189463.aspx) is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You might use something like this:

```
DECLARE @topCount INT = 5;

SELECT TOP(@topCount) * FROM sys.objects;
```

Now with a *do-it-for-all-logic*.

```
SET @topCount=0; --or NULL, or -1 ...

SELECT TOP(CASE WHEN ISNULL(@topCount,0)<=0 THEN 999999999 ELSE @topCount END) * FROM sys.objects;
```

### Attention

You must be aware, that `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` will lead to rather unpredictable results. Which rows are the **first 5** of your table? There is no inherent order...

### UPDATE:

I was to fast. You wanted this behavior as default, when there is no `TOP` specified. Sorry, this is not possible.

Comment: Well, unless he wants to wade into the wonderful world of `SET ROWCOUNT`. He's probably thinking in terms of some SQL clients like SquirrelSql  which limits to 100 rows by default.